# OpenVPN from VPS to Home PC

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, openvpn, vps

I have VPS that is on local network and has local IP assigned. How can I reach it from home PC? Can I run OpenVPN on it and somehow connect to it via VPN?

My VPS is connected to network (I can ping outside, as example 8.8.8.8) but is under NAT. I Can't do port-forward to solve that.

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:67:23:77:05:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

To use OpenVPN you need a way to reach your VPS, that is, having a public IP. The VPS has a public IP, the question is: Is that public IP address exclusive for you, or is it shared?

If it's shared, in your circumstances there's probably nothing to do unless you contact your VPS provider and ask them if you can have a public IP for yourself.

If the IP address is assigned to you and only you, you can install OpenVPN but in terms of connectivity it will add no extra value, as you can reach directly the public IP address, which I believe you're asking for (it might increase security, though).

**EDIT**

An alternative (but untested and also dependent on your configuration) you could achieve connectivity between the two machines, would be installing the OpenVPN server on *your* machine, and make the VPS server a VPN client.

Note that this approach would be dependent on the factors defined above as well: In your home you'd need to make sure you don't have a shared IP, you need to open VPN ports in your router, etc.

This would also need a static IP at your home, but if your ISP doesn't assign static public IPs you can easily achieve one with a free dynamic DNS service, such as [FreeDns.io](https://freedns.io), [noip.com](http://noip.com), or any other...